# center multi level dropdown

Tags: html, dropdown

I've got this working pretty much how I want EXCEPT that the drop down box values are on the left and the rest is properly centered. PLEASE HELP!

I want to keep the level 2 vales to the right of the caret and I've tried everythign I could find online. I'm drawing a total blank.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle center-block" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Pick One
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

      <li><a tabindex="-1">January</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Februrary <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://www.amazon.com/" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1">March</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1">April</a></li>     
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">May <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://www.amazon.com/" target="_blank">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1">June</a></li>      
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">July<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://www.amazon.com/" target="_blank">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to modify your `container` and `dropdown` divs:

1. The `container` needs to center its content
2. The `dropdown` `display` should be changed so that it doesn't automatically take up all the width within its container.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="dropdown open" style="display: inline-block;">
  ....
  </div>
</div>
```